# ViewPager Indicator wont work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I m still new to android and working on my first application. so far so good. among others the app will contain a ViewPager to switch between different xml layouts through swiping. this works nice. 
however I would like to use the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/#introduction) to indicate the position of the displayed template.

so i tried to include the code based on different tutorials/ instructions to my project but the templates/ ViewPager wont show anymore, the app breaks at that point. Thanks for any hints in advance ;)

here is the [code + logCat](http://pastebin.com/mdfC7ZBt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in the xml you have:

```
    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

But you are using `UnderlinePageIndicator` in your code, so it should be:

```
    <com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

Comment: oh man so obvious, thanks so much this does the trick. only thing now is, that the indicator is displayed all over the screen and my linked layouts are not showing. there needs to be something added in those xml layout files as well?

Comment: ok i just adjusted the height to 5dp and it looks nice now. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a typo, your missing a paranthesis in this line:

```
UnderlinePageIndicator indicator = UnderlinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
```

should be

```
UnderlinePageIndicator indicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
```